# Monacaアプリでのカスタムプッシュ通知音再生について

Tags: monaca, push-notification

Monacaでは対応していないプッシュ通知受信時のサウンドについて、どなたかCordovaプラグイン等で実装に成功した方はおりませんでしょうか。

当方、MonacaのAndroidアプリのみ、以下のプラグインにてプッシュ通知音を実装することができましたが、iOSアプリについてはアプリが起動中でないと音を鳴らすことができませんでした。

プッシュ通知送信処理をapns-phpにてサーバーに実装すると、今度は音を鳴らすことは出来たのですが、指定した音声ファイルを再生することはできませんでした。

ニフティのモバイルバックエンドや、Windows Azureとの連携などでも指定した音を鳴らすことに成功している方がいらっしゃいましたら、共有いただけると幸いです。

以下、当方の状況になります。

・Monaca Backendにてプッシュ通知実装
・Cordovaプラグイン「phonegap-plugin-push」にてAndroidアプリのカスタムプッシュ通知音再生に成功
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push
・linuxサーバーからapns-php（https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP）を使用してプッシュ通知を送信した場合、iOSのデフォルトサウンドにてプッシュ通知音再生に成功。